# Перебрать объект и если значение в свойстве это строка то переписать ее всю в верхнем регистре. Использовать for in

Tags: javascript, объекты

6. Дан объект:
   let list = {
   name: ‘denis’,
   work: ‘easycode’,
   age: 29
   }

Comment: И что же вызывает затруднение?

Comment: буквально всё. я не знаю, как выделить все строки в объекте, чтобы перевести их в верхний регистр

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Перебрать значения всех объектов в цикле `for..in`, проверить их на тип с помощью `typeof` и преобразовать к верхнему регистру `toUpperCase()`, если тип равен строке

```
let list = { name: 'denis', work: 'easycode', age: 29 }
for (var prop in list) {
  if(typeof list[prop] === 'string'){
    list[prop] = list[prop].toUpperCase();
    console.log(list[prop]);
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
> "DENIS"
> "EASYCODE"
```

Это самые основы языка, поэтому советую Вам хоть немного [его изучить](https://learn.javascript.ru/js). Тогда такие задачи будете решать легко.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Если моё сообщение оказалось решением Вашей задачи, проголосуйте за него, пожалуйста, и примите как ответ :)